# Sorting in Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is my code

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rpRatesheetDetails" runat="server" 
                        onitemcommand="rpRatesheetDetails_ItemCommand" 
                        onitemdatabound="rpRatesheetDetails_ItemDataBound">
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            <tr>
                                <td width="110" height="25px" class="content">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td style="cursor:pointer;" runat="server" onclick="toggle();">
                                                Carrier
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCarrierSortAsc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_T.png" ToolTip="Sort Ascending Order" style="display:none;"
                                                    CommandName="SortCarrierASC" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnCarrierSortDsc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_B.png" ToolTip="Sort Descending Order" style="display:none;"
                                                    CommandName="SortCarrierDESC" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="110" class="content">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Date
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDateSortAsc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_T.png"  ToolTip="Sort Ascending Order" style="display:none;"
                                                    CommandName="SortDateASC" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDateSortDesc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_B.png" ToolTip="Sort Descending Order" style="display:none;"
                                                    CommandName="SortDateDESC" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="82" class="content">
                                    Call Type
                                </td>
                                <td width="110" class="content">
                                    Format
                                </td>
                                <td width="100" class="content">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                Status
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnStatusAsc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_T.png" ToolTip="Sort Ascending Order" style="display:none;"
                                                    CommandName="SortStatusASC" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnStatusDsc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_B.png" ToolTip="Sort Descending Order" style="display:none;"
                                                    CommandName="SortStatusDESC" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                                <td width="70" class="content">
                                    User
                                </td>
                                <td width="82" class="content">
                                    File Name
                                </td>
                                <td width="110" class="content">
                                    System
                                </td>
                                <td width="110" class="content">
                                    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                No. Of Days
                                            </td>
                                            <td align="right">
                                                <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDaysAsc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_T.png" ToolTip="Sort Ascending Order"
                                                    CommandName="SortNoOfDaysASC" />
                                                 <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDaysDsc" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/Arrow_B.png" ToolTip="Sort Descending Order"
                                                    CommandName="SortNoOfDaysDESC" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </HeaderTemplate>
```

Above is the header template of my repeater.By default when my repeater loads it is sorted by the last column.Now i want dat if the user want to sort by any other column he should click on dat column.Only den the sort icon will be shown and the records will be sorted.I am showing this icon on the ItemDataBound event but how to fire an ItemDataBound event while clicking on header??

Comment: when any one click on header of any column i want to fire ItemDataBound event of repeater

Answer (score 3):

The order of the items in the repeater depends on the order in the bound collection (the `DataSource`).

Sort the items in the `DataSource` before binding in order to get a sorted list in your repeater.

Do this in your `rpRatesheetDetails_ItemCommand` - check the command name, sort the collection accordingly, then bind.

Comment: ya i'm able to do dat but i want to toggle the Ascending and descending icon but its not possible in the ItemCommand event

Comment: you should save sort direction in a property on page. then in itemDataBound set the direction by checking that property.

Comment: @Jay - Have a field telling you what ordering and direction you are using. Populate it in the `ItemCommand` event handler and query it in the `ItemDataBound` event handler for the header template.

Comment: @ShoaibShaikh ya dats rite.But only one column will have the sort icon by default.When the user want to sort by any other column he need to click on the header of that column.In dat case how should i fire an event to go to the  itemDataBound

Comment: @Jay - You can't. The event will fire when you bind the collection, once per item. The `ItemCommand` event handler will fire when you click - that's why you have a `CommandName` on the buttons.

Comment: @Oded den wats the way to sort any other column which does'nt show an sort icon initially

Comment: @Jay - Make the column name clickable, possibly with a server side link, in the event handler do the sorting and binding.